# How to check if every other element is even

Tags: java, algorithm

My code only works for the first index, which just returns `8 true`.

If I change the first index (`nums[0]`) to 9 for example, it skips the `3` and prints `4 true`.

How do I make so that it checks the rest of them (every other element that is) so that it works for every other index?

```
public static boolean solution(int[] nums) {
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if(i % 2 == 0 && nums[i] % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.print(nums[i] + " ");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] nums = {8,3,4,1,6,5,12,1};
    System.out.println(solution(nums));
}
```

Comment: change the augment in your for loop. don't augment with one, augment with two each iteration. Also: don't return true in your for loop. Only return true afterwards. return false if you encounter a value that makes it impossible for all those values to be even

Comment: You stop checking all the elements because you run into the ``return`` in your loop. Try to re-structure that.

Comment: Should the expected output be `8 4 6 12 true` or `8 true 4 true 6 true 12 true`?

Answer (score 4):

You have one (logical) error in your code, and one part that can be improved:

```
public static boolean solution(int[] nums) {
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if(i % 2 == 0 && nums[i] % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.print(nums[i] + " ");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

In your current code, true is returned on the first valid test, which means, you don't test the following cases. Change your code so you'll test them all, and only return during the flow, if you encounter an invalid value.

```
public static boolean solution(int[] nums) {
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if(i % 2 == 0 && nums[i] % 2 != 0) {
            System.out.print(nums[i] + " ");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

A second thing you can improve, is not checking for even indices each iteration. Just augment your i value by two instead of one:

```
public static boolean solution(int[] nums) {
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i+=2) {
        if( nums[i] % 2 != 0) {
            System.out.print(nums[i] + " ");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is check all the even index and look if there are even you can do like this :

```
public static boolean solution(int[] nums) {
   for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
     if(i % 2 == 0 && nums[i] % 2 != 0) {
         System.out.print(nums[i] + " ");
         return false;
     }
   }
   return true;
}
```